# Android Facebook Intent

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using this code to post on Facebook, but it does not work with the official Facebook app because it tries to send as a link. Is there any way around this?

```
Intent s = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

s.setType("text/plain");
s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Quote");
s.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, qoute);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(s, "Quote"));
```

Comment: Can you explain more fully what you mean? Do you mean the facebook application opens when you choose it from the share menu but the EXTRA_TEXT field is a shared URL instead of the message of the share?

Comment: excatly. i use this intent to share text through sms,email,twitter,facebook ect.... the problem is that if i select facebook from the pop up selection the "EXTRA_TEXT, qoute" string is being shared as a url to facebook. this only happens with the facebook app by the dev "facebook".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bug in the official facebook app. I had to code my own activity to do it using the Facebook SDK for Android. See the code sample below.

```
public class FacebookActivity extends Activity implements DialogListener
{

    private Facebook facebookClient;
    private LinearLayout facebookButton;
    private final String APP_API_ID = "XXXXXXXX";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        facebookClient = new Facebook();
        // replace APP_API_ID with your own
        facebookClient.authorize(this, APP_API_ID,
            new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values)
    {

        if (values.isEmpty())
        {
            //"skip" clicked ?

        }

        // if facebookClient.authorize(...) was successful, this runs
        // this also runs after successful post
        // after posting, "post_id" is added to the values bundle
        // I use that to differentiate between a call from
        // faceBook.authorize(...) and a call from a successful post
        // is there a better way of doing this?
        if (!values.containsKey("post_id"))
        {
            try
            {
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", "YOUR TEXT TO SHARE GOES HERE");// the message to post to the wall
                facebookClient.dialog(this, "stream.publish", parameters, this);// "stream.publish" is an API call


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e)
    {       
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e)
    {   
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel()
    {      
        return;     
    }

}
```