# Force Facebook as choice on Android chooser

Tags: android, facebook, url, share

I want to offer a button for sharing the current URL in my app.
I have created a button and using the following code to share:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, newUrl[1]);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, newUrl[0]);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, newUrl[1]));
```

I works great now when Facebook is a choice in the menu.
However stupid it may sound, is it possible to skip the chooser and sen them to the Facebook app directly?
I want to use a Facebook button, and to not confuse people they should not be able to choose other apps in the list. Is this possible at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Facebook Intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481079/android-facebook-intent)

Comment: You mean that I can skip the user and create an activity with his code instead?

Comment: Okey, I hav etried the solution now. It's not at smooth as using the built in. I need an facebook app, people need to accept the permission of the app, log in on facenook via the app. Instead of just get the built in app opened. I should be able to do this via the Facebook upp, if I just know how the built in chooser calls the Facebook-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so I combined a solution to start the Facebook app from your app with the solution to use the intent chooser.

Here is how you skip the chooser and go directly to the Facebook app's ShareActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.SEND");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "URL";
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://title.com");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.ShareLinkActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```