# How to use whatsapp from my Android app?

Tags: android

This is how I am calling the SMS app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text"); 
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");

            startActivity(sendIntent);
```

How do I do the same for sending messages via twitter/Whatsapp/Facebook? What should I write in place of mms-sms? I found no documentation on such.

Comment: Your Accept Score is really low. If you want people to answer your questions, it needs to be higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't also find any way of calling Facebook/Twitter directly, but you could always call `android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND` and let the user choose the application.

[image: Android ACTION_SEND intent]

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message body");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share dialog title"));
```

However, there might be a bug when using this to share through Facebook. For more information please see: [Android Facebook Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481079/android-facebook-intent)

Comment: Tried this ,it is showing only email not showing direct message option ,other chat applications in dialog,how to show them.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {
     try {
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        if (waIntent != null) {
            waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  

    }
```

Comment: Does not check whether WhatsApp is installed or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp

Comment: I have edited my answer. now it checks whether WhatsApp is installed or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
i.putExtra("chat",true);
i.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippets:
For WhatsApp:

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {

        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
   }  
}
```

For Twitter:

```
void shareOnTwitter()
{
    PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String text = "Insert Tweet Here";

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
        //in catch block will be called
        waIntent.setPackage("com.twitter.android");

        waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .show();
        return ;
    }  
    return ;    
}
```