# How can I use the WhatsApp API from Java or Python?

Tags: python, java, api, whatsapp

I am looking for WhatsApp API, preferably a Python or Java library.

I've tried [Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup), but could not get my number registered; I am based in India and I am not sure if that has got anything to do with it.

I did try [WhatsAPI](https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI) (Python library) but it is not working either.

Any suggestions about this? Any users of Yowsup here?

Comment: FYI, on May 2015 WhastAPI repo has been "wiped away" due to legal threats and it's not an option anymore.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

After trying everything, [Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup) library worked for me. The bug that I was facing was recently fixed. Anyone trying to do something with Whatsapp should try it.

Comment: My try with Yowsup was few months back. So my comments could be outdated. But yes, after successfully using Yowsup, when I started getting high traffic, my number was blocked by Whatsapp. I dont know if there has been any change in the policy since then. 

User agent is basically device information. I tried using it as a hack to make whatsapp server believe I was on a mobile device and not a server. But then my number was shut down so I cannot say i was successful.

Answer (score 22):

[From my blog](https://medium.com/@xameeramir/study-on-technical-feasibility-of-whatsapp-bot-implementation-63519d0d0d25)

[courtesy](https://web.whatsapp.com/)

There is a secret pilot program which WhatsApp is working on with selected businesses

- https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/26000052

News coverage:

- https://yourstory.com/2017/09/app-fridays-whatsapp-for-business-bookmyshow/
- https://yourstory.com/2017/09/bookmyshows-product-team-decrypts-how-whatsapp-for-business-works/
- http://indianexpress.com/article/technology/social/now-get-bookmyshow-ticket-confirmation-message-on-whatsapp-4844869/
- http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/news/whatsapp-business-bookmyshow-pilot-1750740

For some of my technical experiments, I was trying to figure out how beneficial and feasible it is to implement bots for different chat platforms in terms of market share and so possibilities of adaptation. Especially when you have bankruptly failed twice, it's important to validate ideas and fail more faster.

Popular chat platforms like [Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/), [Slack](https://api.slack.com/bot-users), [Skype](https://dev.skype.com/bots) etc. have happily (in the sense officially) provided APIs for bots to interact with, but WhatsApp has not yet provided any API.

However, since many years, a lot of activities has happened around this - struggle towards automated interaction with WhatsApp platform:

1. [Bots App](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botsapp)
   Bots App is interesting because it shows that something is really tried and tested.
2. [Yowsup](https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup)
   A project still actively developed to interact with WhatsApp platform.
3. [Yallagenie](http://www.yallagenie.com/) 
   Yallagenie claim that there is a demo bot which can be interacted with at +971 56 112 6652
4. [Hubtype](https://hubtype.com/articles/how-to-create-a-whatsapp-chatbot.html)
   Hubtype is working towards having a bot platform for **WhatsApp for business**.
5. [Fred](https://medium.com/@AlfredBaudisch/how-a-whatsapp-bot-got-famous-and-evolved-as-the-brazilian-wechat-and-conversational-commerce-e2213262183d)
   Fred's task was to automate WhatsApp conversations, however since it was not officially supported by WhatsApp - it was shut down.
6. [Oye Gennie](http://www.oyegennie.com/)
   A bot [blocked](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-build-a-simple-Whatsapp-bot/answer/Ankur-Rastogi?srid=hM8Hz) by WhatsApp.
7. [App/Website to WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012)
   We can use custom URL schemes and Android intent system to interact with WhatsApp but still NOT WhatsApp API.
8. [Chat API daemon](https://github.com/Mawalu/chat-api-daemon)
   Probably created by inspecting the API calls in WhatsApp web version. NOT affiliated with WhatsApp.
9. [WhatsBot](https://devpost.com/software/whatsbot#updates)
   Deactivated WhatsApp bot. Created during a [hackathon](https://techcrunch.com/2015/12/06/whatsbot-brings-a-virtual-assistant-to-whatsapp/).
10. [No API claim](http://mashable.com/2015/03/25/whatsapp-developers-api/#CvXpmtrjROqA)
    WhatsApp co-founder clearly stated this in a conference that they did not had any plans for APIs for WhatsApp.
11. [Bot Ware](https://www.botware.com.br/messenger-and-whatsapp-chatbot-development/)
    They probably are expecting WhatsApp to release their APIs for chat bot platforms.
12. [Vixi](http://vixi.io/)
    They seems to be talking about how some platform which probably would work for WhatsApp. There is no clarity as such.
13. [Unofficial API](https://market.mashape.com/datayuge/whatsapp)
    This API can shut off any time.

    And the number goes on...

Answer (score 8):

WhatsApp Inc. does not provide an open API but a reverse-engineered library is made available on GitHub by the team Venomous on the GitHub. This however according to my knowledge is made possible in PHP. You can check the link here: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI

Hope this helps