# Can I create a plugin for whatsapp

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am have an idea and I want to create a plugin for whatsapp on android lets say by installing my application will add more emoticons to whatsapp. I have been searching about it but I have add no luck, can anyone tell me is this possible if yes then any help will be much appreciated.

How can I add the button of my app on top like this one

I want to create something like this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidsx.smileys

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whatsapp API (java/python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135496/whatsapp-api-java-python)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135496/whatsapp-api-java-python

Comment: I want to add some features to existing whatsapp whereas Yowsup provides with all capabilities of creating our own whatsapp. If you see first image of https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidsx.smileys 
you will see they have their own icon on whatsapp, how are they doing it

Comment: That button is not integrated into whatsapp, it is a floating button that only shows up when you have a chat screen open. There is no API for whatsapp itself, so using these kind of hacks or building your own client is the way to go.