# How to Send message to a WhatsApp group without opening WhatsApp?

Tags: android, messaging, whatsapp

Is it possible to send message using the WhatsApp server to a WhatsApp group, 
inside my own application and without opening the WhatsApp app?

Also please help me regarding the history of WhatsApp contact chat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in short **NO**

**Reason:** because *(at least to my knowledge)* Whatsapp does not allows the same. i.e. no external events or APIs to implement the same. So you have to at least **use the intents** and let the user handle the rest.

> Also please help me regarding the history of WhatsApp contact chat.

This also can't be done ***(using ethical approach)*** because all the chat history is stored in a private database which is not revealed to the external apps by the Whatsapp application and also potentially violates the users privacy.

Comment: You can always look at the answers listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135496/whatsapp-api-java-python.

Comment: @ramizmoh is it an official API by whatsapp?

Comment: @SMR No, it is not but can be used for educational purposes.

Comment: yes it can be used but its not reliable because whatapp can update anytime and then this may longer work. but thanks for sharing it anyways. :)

Comment: I agree, though there is a team of developers constantly keeping it up to date. :)

Comment: Yowsup is the core engine behind Whatsapp . that can be used to almost do anything with whatsapp

Comment: @Abid ***"Yowsup is the core engine behind Whatsapp"*** really.. well I don't think so. It is created and maintained by its (sort of) community. If it was.. then whatsapp.com would have provided links in the developers section. but infact **there is no developers section in the site**. Please verify your statement before posting :)

Comment: @SMR Sorry for wrong wording. basically it is the core engine behind WhazzApp.