# Does WhatsApp offer APIs?

Tags: whatsapp

Is there an API to access WhatsApp through an internet protocol?

For example, I'm wondering if there's a way to send a message to a list of WhatsApp users from an internet server?

Comment: I have started an OpenAPI Specification on GitHub for "WhatsApp Business API": https://unblu.github.io/WhatsApp-Business-API-OpenAPI/ feel free to contribute.

Answer (score 23):

WhatsApp is a closed system without an API for general external user access;
see *[Unauthorized use of automated or bulk messaging on WhatsApp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/5957850900902049/)* for more reading in that regard. They do offer a [suite of business APIs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp) for interacting with business accounts and with customers of those businesses programmatically (e.g. for marketing or sales purposes).

There *were* [several projects available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135496/whatsapp-api-java-python) that reverse engineered the WhatsApp web service interfaces. However, to my knowledge all of them are now discontinued/defunct due to legal action against them from WhatsApp.

For mobile phone applications, there is a limited URL-Scheme-API available on [iPhone](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) and [Android](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012) (Android-intent possible as well).