# Send messages to Whatsapp number using PHP

Tags: php, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have to send messages to the customer's **whatsapp number** programatically.

What are the pre requirements/needs?

Do I need to convert/register my personal number to business account?

Is there any **API** provided by **whatsapp** for this?

Comment: These sound like questions you should research from WhatsApp directly.

Comment: Did you see this link https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation?

Comment: mgp25 library is outdated and no longer supported since 2016, so it's not an option as it's not working anymore

Comment: WhatsApp has no API, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078108/does-whatsapp-offer-an-open-api

Comment: Whatsapp API is out for public use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview

Comment: Whatsapp API https://www.creativepoint.in/whatsapp-api-service-company-in-coimbatore.html

Answer (score 15):

WhatsApp just launched business api recently

What are the pre requirements/needs?

Please submit a form at https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api to sign up

Do I need to convert/register my personal number to business account?

You need to register a phone number as business account, after registration, you cannot use whatsapp app with the same number on your device. So it's better to register business account with another number rather than your personal number

Is there any API provided by whatsapp for this?

Please check out https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api for more information

Comment: Is this API free?

Comment: @Simone Yes the API is free.

Comment: It is not free. It is free for up to 1000 conversations each months. https://business.whatsapp.com/products/platform-pricing

Answer (score 9):

> Do I need to convert/register my personal number to business account?

Not necessarily, it's your choice if you want to share your personal account, even though you recommend using a business account

> Is there any **API** provided by **whatsapp** for this?

According to Whatsapp's own documentation, they do not have a direct API, but you can create a link to send the messages, according to the documentation, follow the submission parameter by the URL: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=`

Here's another example:

**Use**: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567`

**Don't use**: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+001-(555)1234567`

You can see more in: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/

---

**UPDATE APRIL, 24 2022**

Whatsapp sender API url has been changed to: `https://wa.me/<number>`

Example:

**Use**: `https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX`

**Don't use**: `https://wa.me/+001-(XXX)XXXXXXX`

Comment: Does this example use `PHP` for sending message? This is a message link only that user will click to trigger `WhatsApp` and then send message.

Comment: this exp start chating, i dont  want to , i just want to send a text message in user whats app with php in wordpress,can you help?

Answer (score -8):

On 2020 06 06 this works

```html
For existing phone numbers: 
<a href=\"whatsapp://send?phone=--your phone--&text=--your text--\"> 
For non existing phone numbers: 
<a href=\"https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=--your phone--&text=--your text--\">
```

Comment: The OP asked for a programatical solution.