# How to Login with WhatsApp in Android and iOS Apps?

Tags: android, ios, whatsapp

We have a requirement for login with WhatsApp in one of my Android and iOS app, the way we do it with Google and Facebook login. We also need to get the profile data and contact list pertaining to the respective WhatsApp login so can anybody help me on this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078108/does-whatsapp-offer-an-open-api

Answer (score 1):

Kind of the point of WhatsApp is that it's intentionally secure.  It's not going to allow you to get contact lists.  You can use click to chat via their Whatsapp by calling https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567 as per https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000030/?category=5245251.  Just look up API on https://faq.whatsapp.com for the full list of integrations with Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Used [OTPless](https://otpless.com) in one of my previous company. They provide seamless Login via Whatsapp Solution (SSO). It's free and easy to integrate with any platform.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32602673)