# How to send a message to Whatsapp using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have some questions:

1. How to send a message to Whatsapp using Spring Boot? Is there an API ready to be used?
2. Is the traffic of the message, whether for receiving or sending, is paid? If so, how does the payment for this service, charged by characters or bit size of the information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does WhatsApp offer an open API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078108/does-whatsapp-offer-an-open-api)

Answer (score 1):

I found this article: [whatsappmate](https://whatsmate.github.io/2016-02-17-send-whatsapp-message-java/) article online, it seems like you can register your phone number with the API gateway but there will be a limitation to the number of messages you can send.

Also, there is a Whatsapp service from [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/quickstart/java) which is not free. You can check out their pricing [here.](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037672734-How-Much-Does-it-Cost-to-Send-and-Receive-WhatsApp-Messages-with-Twilio-#:%7E:text=Twilio%20charges%20a%20flat%20fee,the%20destination%20country%20or%20region.) I have used their APIs for SMS and VOICE calls and they were rich. So, I could expect their WHATSAPP API to be richer also.

Comment: Sensational! Thank you @Adhitha Dias!
Will it be to test during the development, Twilio's Whatsapp service, there is an option for sending messages free? If so, do you know how many messages can be tested per day?