# ETL for whatsapp data to SQL or other database

Tags: sql, database, nosql, etl, whatsapp

I want to read WhatsApp data(the group that I managing them and the phone number of the users who are in these group and their activity, and everything that I have in my WhatsApp) to some SQL server but unfortunately can't find a way to do it automatically and schedule it, (i found just some offline way)
can someone kindly help me with it?

Comment: Do you mean you are using an api provided by WhatsApp? Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: no, I don't have an API, I was using the backup file that WhatsApp gives you, actually, I am looking for some API or method that can read data from WhatsApp and schedule it

Comment: did you have a chance to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078108/does-whatsapp-offer-an-open-api)?