# send message on whatsapp number using whatsApp API

Tags: c#, asp.net, whatsapp, whatsapi

As I need to send message on user's whatsapp number so I have downloaded WhatsApp API from nuget packages.
and also I implemented code according to that. But after so many search I found that I need to register mobile number to get password...using WART but I think this application is not working and not able to get password from WhatsApp.

So if anyone implement this feature of sending message on whatsapp number in Asp.net c# then please update me how to do this using WhatsApp Api..
even I don't know whatsapp is provide any API or not.

I have tried with below code...but I need password before that..

```
            string fromMob = "919xxxxxxxxx";
            string toMob = txtMobileNo.Text.Trim();
            string msg = "This is first WhatsApp Message Whatsapp API";

            WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(fromMob, "RequiredPassword", "SD", false, false);

            try
            {
                wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
                {
                    wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
                    {
                        wa.SendMessage(toMob, msg);

                    };

                    wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
                        {
                            msg = "Login Failed" + data;
                        };
                };

                wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
                    {
                        msg = "Connection Failed" + ex;
                    };
                wa.Connect();
            }
            catch { }
```

Comment: I thought the WhatsApp API had been disabled years ago.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46635985/982149

Comment: It's definitely doesn't work. I think the only way is to use WhatsMate or similar service. But I can't say if they work for sure. Haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 3):

**[WhatsApp Business API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/getting-started)** is live now. Please refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp) for detailed information.

> The WhatsApp Business API Client supports a subset of the features
>   provided by the WhatsApp applications you already know from Android,
>   iOS, Web and other platforms including end-to-end encryption. The
>   difference is that this application can be deployed on a server,
>   providing a local API that allows you to programmatically send and
>   receive messages and integrate this workflow with your own systems
>   (CRMs, customer care, etc.).
>
> Please note that if you use anything other than the official WhatsApp
>   Business API or other official WhatsApp tools, we reserve the right to
>   limit or remove your access to WhatsApp as this violates our policies.
>   Please do not use any non-WhatsApp authorized third-party tools to
>   communicate on WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Whatsapp API](https://chat-api.com/en/?lang=EN) documentation,

In the documentation, you can go API docs of send message, read message, set webhook APIs

Comment: This is not owned by whatsapp this is third party I think.

Comment: It is not working since 2021. There is guy who mantains actual list of unnoficial whatsapp api providers. You can find the list here https://github.com/yredsmih/whatsapp-blacklisted-providers