# Sending message through WhatsApp By intent

Tags: android, android-intent, send, whatsapp

How I can send massage from my app to Special number in whatsapp , I know this code to share massage to group or contact on whatsapp

```
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("text/plain");
String text = "Sorry For Interruption,I'm Just Trying Something";
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

if (waIntent != null) {
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);//
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent,"Share with"));
```

but I want send massage to  Special number like "966xxxxxxx" how I can do that ?

Comment: There's no way to do that unless whatsapp have the ability to do so.

Comment: You need whatsapp to understand extra fields in your intent. So if whatsapp can't do this, you have no way to achieve your goal. Try to search for documentation about whatsapp BroadcastReveivers and how Intents are parsed.

Comment: Thank you , I found Solution :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending message through WhatsApp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is a Solution :

```
private void openWhatsApp(String id) {

Cursor c = getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver()
            .query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                  new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID },  
                  ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
                  new String[] { id }, 
                  null);

c.moveToFirst();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
              Uri.parse(
                   "content://com.android.contacts/data/" +           
                    c.getString(0)));

startActivity(i);
c.close();
}
```

Where id is what's app uri like 966123456789@s.whatsapp.net

Comment: Is it really work?, the code can send whatsapp message? or just view a contact message?

Comment: @Sieryuu it just open the chat history for a specific contact.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for sending data to perticuler a number

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));}
```

thats realy works for me
enjoy your code:)

Comment: it just open the chat console for that number. The message is passed into the chat console. Intent.createChooser(i, "message") got no effect too.

Comment: Hi John, is there a way I send to a group ?

Comment: Not Yet. as per my knowledge.