# How to get getSherlockActivity()?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I am trying for a code that sends message using WhatsApp Application.  I found a useful code at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931758/2567598).

When I paste the code into my eclipse it start showing me error for undefined method `getSherlockActivity()`.

I tired import library files using <kbd>ctrl+shift+o</kbd> key and <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> key. But it seems this method requires any special kind of library ( .jar ) file. I tried to search on google, but could not successed init.

Can anyone please where can I get this method ?

Comment: what does your activity extend?

Comment: extend SherlockActivity

Comment: You can find the jar file here http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: @sayed.jalil, I found it, can you please post it as answer so that I can accept it and it can be helpful for future user.

Comment: Glad it worked. I have posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the Sherlock library. You can find it Here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use `getActivity()` instead, if you are not using Sherlock Library and you are inside `Fragment`. If you are using this code inside an `Activity` then you can just start with `getContentResolver()...`.

Answer (score 0):

include the Sherlock library and use extend SherlockActivity not extend Activity