# Android - getting an error “no application can perform this action” while trying to send a whatsapp message?

Tags: java, android

I am practising by making an app in which the user can send a WhatsApp message to a particular person .I tried some code snippets which i found on internet but whenever i try to send a WhatsApp msg from an actual device, i am gettig an error "No Application can perform this action".

Here is my code:-

```
public void sendMessage(View v) {
   try
   {
    String whatsAppMessage = message.getText().toString();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "9888873438");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
   }catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
}
```

Please help .

Comment: ... do you have WhatsApp installed?

Comment: Yes, i have whatsapp installed .

Comment: I did something by sending an eMail, instead of an sms. With optional attachments, It not only works with the eMail client/s, but also with a plethora of different apps, amongst which, Telegram (an open source WhatsApp clone).

Comment: So what do you think might be wrong in here ?

Comment: Try the given answers. It may work. My code is somewhat more generic.

Comment: My code is more similar to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15497092/2649012

Comment: yeah this is somewhat similar to mine ,god knows what's wrong in here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive *no application can perform this action* because you should remove `i.setType("text/plain");` from your code:

```
String whatsAppMessage = message.getText().toString();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "9888873438");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));
```

Unfortunately as you can see WhatsApp now opens in the conversation activity but there isn't the text you set in the `Intent`. This is because WhatsApp doesn't support this kind of share. The only supported share with Intent is `ACTION_SEND` as you can see in the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/android/28000012):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: I tried after deleting i.setType("text/plain"); but still getting the same pop up saying no "application can perform this action".Please explicitly say that if it is possible or not to send the message this way.Regarding the FAQ, i already know that.

Comment: No, it's not possible to send a message directly to a particular person. You need to use the solution explained in WhatsApp FAQ and let the user choose the contact.

Comment: Can you explain me the reason for this ?

Comment: There isn't any reason for this, It's a decision of WhatsApp developers.

Comment: is there any other way out to send a message to whatsapp ?

Comment: From what I know, the only methods available is the ones included in WhatsApp FAQ.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sparing time and guiding ,you deserve an upvote.