# How can I share text in what's app on particular Number

Tags: android, whatsapp

Using this code only open particulat number's chat but Text is not share.How can I do this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button Wa;
String id = "+919000000000";
EditText txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Wa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_whatsapp);
    Wa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + id);
            Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);

            String text = "testing message";
            waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            if (waIntent != null) {
                waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, text));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

         }
    });

}
```

Comment: how send sms same as in whatsup http://stackoverflow.com/q/9798657/1168654

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19179175/1168654

Comment: Try like this  Intent waIntent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        waIntent.setType("text/plain");

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar i'll try all the way which is given in ur link.. but its not work

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar  new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); waIntent.setType("text/plain");   using this open whats app and the select any number.. but i want to share text on particalu number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you trying to achieve it as `"smsto:"`, `"text/plain"` as type will help you. Try Extra as `"sms_body"` if it won't help.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + id);
Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
String text = "testing message";
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (waIntent != null) {
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
    //waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    waIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text); 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, text));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}
```

Comment: instead of "text/plain", try uysing "message/rfc822"

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this stackoverflow links

1. [Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp/15931345#15931345)
2. [Send text to specific contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19081654/send-text-to-specific-contact-whatsapp)

> It seems that **WhatsApp** still does't have supported this fetaure.
>   You can only open chat history for particular number using below code

```
try {
            Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:+98xxxxxxxx");
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
            mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

//            mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "My body");
            mIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");

            startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // alert WhatsApp in not installed
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button Wa;
    String id = "+919000000000";
    EditText txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Wa = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_whatsapp);
        Wa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
                try {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    String text = "testing message";

                    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, text));
                }   
                catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  
             }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627699/how-to-send-a-text-message-and-image-through-whatsapp-from-own-application-with/30132967#30132967)

Earlier it wasn't possible but since the May '15 update. Checkout :

```
try{
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String sendString = "some random string";
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sendString);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
} catch (Exception e){
    // some code
}
```

Here PackageInfo line is just to check if WhatsApp is installed. It throws Exception if not. You can just ignore that if you want to do a normal share (and setPackage also).

Also. It is important that the media you want to share has to be publicly  available on local storage.

**UPDATE**

To send to a specific contact

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "<CONTACT_NUMBER>");
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
```

As Action *Send To* is now allowed.