# How to share Image and text both together on WhatsApp to a specific recipient?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, whatsapp

I am trying to send image and text to whatsapp directly to specific recipient, but only text is send

```
    String msg = "Message here";
    Uri bitmapUri= Uri.parse(imageUrl);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+smsNumber +"&text="+msg);

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri+"?image="+bitmapUri));
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error/n" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: [check this link get you given answer inside of this link ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077338/share-image-and-text-through-whatsapp-or-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

please visit this answer
[How to Send a Text message and Image through Whatsapp from Own Application with help of Intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627699/how-to-send-a-text-message-and-image-through-whatsapp-from-own-application-with)

Answer (score 0):

You can send image using this code.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.test/drawable/image_1");
                sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg"); 
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri); 
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```