# How to pass a specific text to a specific number through WhatsApp?

Tags: android, whatsapp

I have this code. It is only opening WhatsApp with a particular number but not with text.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" +mobilenumber);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.putExtra("sms_body", "Hello StackOverFlow");
i.putExtra("chat",true);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(i);
```

I have tried using `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` but no result.

How to pass the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly send message to specific contact in whatsapp from your code. you can pass text to listing screen then user can choose user to send the message.

Try below code:

```
 final Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
 whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
 whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
 try {
       mContext.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
 } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
       Toast.makeText(mContext, "WhatsApp is not installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

**EDIT:**

you can not Send Whatsapp message to specific contact. Refer [Send Whatsapp message to specific contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892396/send-whatsapp-message-to-specific-contact?lq=1)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply.   i am able to open whatsapp chat for that particular number with my code. only thing i need to send the text as i am sending number .

Comment: it's for sending message without opening whatsapp

Comment: Please Look at my  Question.i want to send to particular number only

Comment: Yes i know your question but whasapp does not allow to directly send message to specific number.

Comment: the code you have provided. it only opens particular contact chat screen but does not pass any message because whasapp is not allowing it