# send an image to the current whatsapp contact conversation

Tags: android, whatsapp

I saw that there is a way to send an image to a specific phone number
using the jid key value
But I need to add an image to the current conversation
So maybe the question is how to get programmatically the current contact from whatsapp with out opening the chat history

I looked at this answer
 [Send Whatsapp message to specific contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892396/send-whatsapp-message-to-specific-contact)
but didnt managed to find the answer

Comment: did you figure it out?