# Sending Whatsapp messages to unsaved contacts in QPython

Tags: android, python, whatsapp

There seems to be a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892396/send-whatsapp-message-to-specific-contact/41805649)
in Java (I guess). For clarity I will paste the code:

```
try {
            PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ phone +"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Now I've been trying to achive the same using QPython and Androidhelper (I guess this is just SL4A) and my attempt looks like this:

```
import androidhelper
droid = androidhelper.Android()

activity = 'android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW'

packagename =  'com.whatsapp'
uri='http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=*********&text=TEST'
uritype='UTF-8'

intent = droid.makeIntent(activity, uri, None,None,None, packagename, None,None).result
droid.startActivityIntent(intent,None)
```

I'm not sure what 'uritype' should be set to. Further, I've no clue, whether 'Intent.ACTION_VIEW' is correct. I've tried several variations such as 'android.intent.action.ACTION_VIEW'. 'android.intent.ACTION_VIEW', 'Android.Intent.ACTION_VIEW' etc.

I guess the most critical part however is the 'classname'-Attribute (2nd to last one) The (poorly documented) SL4A API [help](http://www.qpython.org/en/guide_androidhelpers.html) says that this attribute needs to be specified in case 'packagename' is specified.

Any ideas?

The script runs without giving any warnings or errors. Since I'm a 'C'-person I'm very confused because I've no idea where to start searching for my mistake.