# Sending message to WhatsApp from code in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, whatsapp

As I know one can send message to whatsapp by invoking Intent from third party application . Something  like this I found here [Sending message through WhatsApp By intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768688/sending-message-through-whatsapp-by-intent).

I want to do the same in blackberry OS 7.I am developing an application which have a button which onclick send message to whatsapp number specified in program. If whatsapp is not installed in phone it just display message "Whatsapp is installed on Device" .

To do the same I have searched a lot but whatever example I found was of Android.

Please suggest if this is possible in blackberry?

Thanks