# How to send the Pre-populated text message to specific (intended) Whats-App user / users?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I want to send Some **Pre-populated** text message to **specific user/users** ,
I did the google and i came across some same kind of questions on stack overflow like

[Send message to specific number whatsapp android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943480/send-message-to-specific-number-whatsapp-android)
[Send message to specific number whatsapp android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943480/send-message-to-specific-number-whatsapp-android)

and

[Android: How to send message programatically by using whats app , We chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774595/android-how-to-send-message-programatically-by-using-whats-app-we-chat)
[Android: How to send message programatically by using whats app , We chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774595/android-how-to-send-message-programatically-by-using-whats-app-we-chat)

but i am not able to get the *relevant* solutions for intended task.

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: thnx .but the requirement  is send message to specific user of whats app.

Comment: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012 you cant send to specific person anymore..

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "123456789");
         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
         i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
         
         i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your text here");
        // startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "gg"));
         startActivity(i);

Comment: I posted my source code it just open the chat screen of that specific user but the text i use in code is not displayed in that chatting screen.

Comment: that's not possible. it just open specific user and you need to manually give message. Only way is intent share what @Dhina specified.