# Message with phone number and sms_body via whatsapp android

Tags: android, message, whatsapp, sendto

I have this code to send message via whatsapp

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + PhoneNumber);
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Some text");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

but when whatsapp is started it filled with the phone number but not with the text provided (also i've tried with `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending message through WhatsApp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

Comment: that code not work for me :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34172509/how-to-send-the-pre-populated-text-message-to-specific-intended-whats-app-user#comment56092384_34172509

Comment: thanks, is not possible send a specific text...