# Open Contact's Chat window in WeChat

Tags: android, wechat

Is it possible to send message to a specific contact through WeChat directly from another app? I know the contact ID. I want to open that contact's chat window when I Click on the WeChat button in my android application.

Answer (score -2):

it depends on WeChat's code. If they have intent filters for certain Intent Action's and you define the package of wechat, you can send the message via wechat from your app OR open the window.

See :

[Send message to specific contact through whatsapp from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339150/send-message-to-specific-contact-through-whatsapp-from-another-app)

and

https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012

Ideally some similar documentation should be available for WeChat as well

Comment: its not available. Please check question. Its about wechat