# How to share .gif file with in other App using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

How to share .gif file in any of below Android apps:

1. Whatsapp
2. Snapchat
3. Google Talk
4. Line
5. Viber
6. Skype
7. Facebook Messenger

Using intent call for each apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Whatsapp you can use this:

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
waIntent.setType("image/gif");
waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (waIntent != null) {
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

}
```

For the other apps you can choose the same scheme I think.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: for me it doesn't work

Comment: try this:
    `private void ShareGif() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        Uri gifUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+ "Download/1027"+".gif"));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, gifUri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share GIF"));
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to share with specific applications you have to use URIs of this application.
You can fin example and explanations for Skype here : http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris

But if you want to share with all applications available, you just have to set the content type as a binary file as explained here : http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Comment: Thanks for reply.sent link for skype is ok for me.Do you know same methods for others apps.

Comment: You just have to make a search like "Android Whatsapp uri" and the first answer is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp I think doing the same for other applications will give the solution.