# cursor count is 0 when getting contact from cursor

Tags: android

I am running this code from this  [Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp#17936420)

```
Cursor c = getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
        new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID }, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
        new String[] { whatsappid }, null);  
c.moveToFirst();
```

But the cursor count which I am getting is 0

I am using whatsappid as 911234567890
where 91 is country code

Please Help me out

Comment: eliminate your countrycode(+91) from it

Comment: i did but still it is not working

Comment: is this no 1234567890 present in your phone contact then only it returns

Comment: No this is only sample number but on which number I am trying that is present in my contact list.