# Send WhatsApp message to a contact

Tags: android, whatsapp

I want to send a whatsapp message from my app to a particular whatsapp contact. I have tried the answers posted on other questions on this site. None of it seems to work. It is possible to achieve it through root access as its been done in this app : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.future.whatsauto2

Any help on how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp

Comment: I tried already, It just opens the contacts list. It doesnt send the message automatically.