# How to send particular message to a particular phone number in whatsapp from my app programatically

Tags: android, whatsapp

Here I am trying to send the message hello world to a number.
Here is My code snippet:

```
public void openWhatsappContact(String number) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);

    i.setType("text/plain");

    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World");

    i.putExtra("chat",true);

    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));

}
```

But its showing error:

```
No applications can perform this action
```

Comment: and is it certainly installed? try to use the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp it tests if whatsapp is installed by using packagemanager

Comment: Same for me. Whatsapp is installed on my device