# Sending a message in what's app particular number through my app

Tags: android, android-intent, social-networking, sharing, whatsapp

Hello Friends i Want to Send a message in what's app particular number define by me in my java file. i followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp) and include below code in my project.

```
public void sendWhatsAppMessageTo(String whatsappid) {

 Cursor c = getSherlockActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts.Data._ID }, ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + "=?",
    new String[] { whatsappid }, null);
c.moveToFirst();

Intent whatsapp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data/" + c.getString(0)));
c.close();

if (whatsapp != null) {

startActivity(whatsapp);      

} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
//download for example after dialog
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
}

}
```

and it throws the cursorindexoutofboundexception:Index 0 requested with size of 0.please help me to solve this problem