# How to open Whatsapp from other app

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am developing an android app.
I want to open (just open) WhatsApp from my app.

How can I open WhatsApp from my app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try this

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Comment: Is there a way to open a chat to specific contact?

Comment: @Amsheer, How can I open a specific whatsapp contact directly from my application?