# sharing message to whatsapp from my android app

Tags: android

i have one android app and in mobile browser i open that page and click on whatsapp icon it will be easily shared to whatsapp.but same thing and same page is loaded in webview and tried to share it gives error,

i searched few pages and found this link

[Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

i copied these codes in my mainactivity.java and saved but then the eclipse gives error.codes contains error so it cant be exported.

any guide how to achieve this

Comment: You have to show the error and describe when exactly it happens. Also it's easier to understand what is wrong with your code when you show it rather  than just link to copied code.

Comment: @Foxinsocks its general error