# How to implement a "share on whatsapp" feature in a custom Android app?

Tags: java, php, android

i have read several already answered article on this site and used this 
[Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

i am able to share from chrome but not from app.

my code is

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

 PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
 try {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
    //in catch block will be called
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

    }  

 }
```

when i click on share button in my android app whatsapp icon it gives error page not found but when same thing is shared from chrome it just works fine.

my url is http://way2enjoy.com/app/jokes.php

if anyone can guide where the mistake is i will be thankful

Comment: Do it the same way, just call the `whatsapp://` protocol.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf <a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=Dil me har kisi ko pane ka arman nahi hota.&lt;br /&gt;  Har koi dil ka mehaman nahi hota.&lt;br /&gt;  Lelin jo ban jate hai apne use bhula pana aasan nahi hota." data-action="share/whatsapp/share" ><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>

Comment: Yes, use the same approach as on the web in the mobile as the `whatsapp://` protocol will launch whatsapp. ;)

Comment: @HassanAlthaf when it is working in chrome so website code is correct but i have to add whatsapp support in app.which i have added in above code .then also it is not working

Comment: @HassanAlthaf anywhere i have to add this in app?? i am loading weburl through webview so  i dont think this is required in app

Comment: @manan-merevik-sharma can u plz help

Answer (score 0):

you can use my code which works for me

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));}
```

enjoy your code time:)

Comment: replaced my question codes with ur codes.but same error.page not found.its not working

Comment: @anamika please replace content type to */* insteed of text/plain in my last comment.

Comment: where is content type in above code void openWhatsappContact(String number) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));}

Comment: dear last code
code start from 
//method used to show IMs comment

Comment: plz help i m unable to share

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code also

```
//method used to show IMs
private void show_custom_chooser(String value) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = null;
    final Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "" + value);
    email.setType("text/plain"); // vnd.android-dir/mms-sms

    WindowManager.LayoutParams WMLP = dialogCustomChooser.getWindow()
            .getAttributes();
    WMLP.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    dialogCustomChooser.getWindow().setAttributes(WMLP);
    dialogCustomChooser.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialogCustomChooser.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialogCustomChooser.setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);
    dialogCustomChooser.setCancelable(true);
    ListView lvOfIms = (ListView) dialogCustomChooser
            .findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm.queryIntentActivities(email, 0);
    // ////////////new
    list = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>();
    for (int i = 0; i < launchables.size(); i++) {
        String string = launchables.get(i).toString();
        Log.d("heh", string);
//check only messangers
        if (string.contains("whatsapp")) {
            list.add(launchables.get(i));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(list, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
    int size = launchables.size();
    adapter = new AppAdapter(pm, list, MainActivity.this);
    lvOfIms.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvOfIms.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            ResolveInfo launchable = adapter.getItem(position);
            ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
                    activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            email.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            email.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            email.setComponent(name);
            startActivity(email);
            dialogCustomChooser.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogCustomChooser.show();

}
```

Comment: Oooo..let me chek and tell you with in 10 min.

Comment: untill change text/plan to */* in your code that you posted.