# Send text/message via whatsapp from backend website

Tags: php, android, e-commerce, whatsapp

I've customer that i need to send message or question about their orders via backend (PHP) which is via their mobile number (through whatsapp - android). And i know it works using this script:

```
<a href="intent:<?php echo $row['mobile']; ?>#Intent;scheme=smsto;
package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">
Message via Whatsapp</a>
```

But only works for existing contact or i've conversation earlier, not for new contacts. Is it possible to save the mobile to contact if its new? Or any better suggestions? pre-filled? etc...

or this post related?
[Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)