# Android: How can I open a different app with my notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I have been trying out how to make a notification for my app open up a different application such as inbox.  I have only seen how to open a specific activity and don't know if it is possible to open an entire application.

Comment: I think it is possible.. You just need to configure the intent properly... But I never tried.. so, I can't confirm

Comment: There is no "entire application" in Android. That is akin to asking how to link to an "entire Web site" from your Web page. You can start a launcher activity for the application, given that you know its application ID ("package name") to use with `PackageManager`. Since not everybody uses Google Inbox, you would need some way to allow users to decide what application you should open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. You just need to configure your intent properly.

**CAUTION**

End user may not have installed the app that you want.. So, you have to implement methods to control that...

But anyway, it is possible to open a different app from your own notification

**Example**

I created example below for whatsapp. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp/15931345#15931345) as reference.

```
Notification.Builder notiBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
Intent intent = null;

/*
    START
    Configure your intent here.
    Example below opens the whatspp.. I got this example from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp/15931345#15931345
    You must update it to open the app that you want.

    If the app is not found, intent is null and then, click in notification won't do anything
*/
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
try {
    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Package not found
    intent = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*  END  */

if(intent != null) {
    PendingIntent clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notiBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_light)
            .setContentText("Message")
            .setContentIntent(clickPendingIntent)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);
} else {
    notiBuilder.setContentTitle("Title")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_light)
            .setContentText("Message")
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000);
}

Notification mNotificationBar = notiBuilder.build();
mNotificationBar.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
mNotificationBar.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
mNotificationBar.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBar);
```

**Open Dialer**

Just configure the intent like below:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
```

Comment: Cool, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official docs on how to create an implicit intent.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Is this what you meant?