# How to send message to a number from my android app via whatsapp?

Tags: android

I have made an android app on android studio, from that application I want to send a message to a number but via whatsapp. The number is not in my contact list. I have tried the following code found on stackoverflow:

```
Uri mUri = Uri.parse("smsto:+999999999");
Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The text goes here");
mIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

But it throws an exception "Activity not found".

I have also found one code but it opens the chat screen which I don't want means the user should only get a toast that message is sent and not any other
screen.

If anybody has a solution please let me know.

Comment: Did you try this - [Sending message through WhatsApp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931345/3398732) ?

Comment: You cannot send a message without user interaction, that is a terrible idea. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp) and the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/de/android/28000012).

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClickWhatsApp(View view) {

PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
try {

    Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    waIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String text = "YOUR TEXT HERE";

    PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp",  
    PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    //Check if package exists or not. If not then code 
    //in catch block will be called
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(waIntent, "Share with"));

    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
    }  

    }
```

try this,or check this link  [sharingwithwhatsapp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

Answer (score 0):

**

1. I find this Code stuff from my friend website

---

**

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.code2care.example.whatsappintegrationexample.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessae"
    android:layout_marginBottom="21dp"
    android:text="Send to WhatsApp" />

    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:hint="Type your WhatsApp message here ...."
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFFFFEF"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:ems="10" />
```

**activity_main.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private EditText message;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);

    }

    public void sendMessage(View v) {

        String whatsAppMessage = message.getText().toString();

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, whatsAppMessage);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

        // Do not forget to add this to open whatsApp App specifically
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(sendIntent);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below mentioned code is used to direct the **chat** on **Whatsapp** on any number via android application :

```
 String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+9194xxxxxxxx";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
```