# Sending message to multiple contacts at once, via whatsapp, android studio

Tags: android

I want to send message to multiple contacts **at once** , via whatsapp. I know that it is posible via whatsapp broadcast, but **problem** is I dont know how to realize it by code, in android studio. I searched about it, but didn't find anything. Does anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To send a message from your app to multiple contacts in WhatsApp

```
      String message = "Health worker uploaded a data";
        Context context_new=this.getApplicationContext();

        packageManager = context_new.getPackageManager();
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        try {

            //only message and ability to send message to multiple nos.
            String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");

            i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

            if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                context_new.startActivity(i);
                Log.d(TAG, "Watsapp message successful"+ "passed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Watsapp message failed"+ "failed");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here i m sharing audio file to multiple contact via whatsapp..

```
lblshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String valueofpathh = recordName.getText().toString();
                        File filee = new File(valueofpathh);
                        try {
                            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
                            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(filee));
                            startActivity(sendIntent);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodError | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

i hope its help you to understand.

here valueOfPath is my string that contain my device sdcard folder path, so i can get all audio file from that path.

if you have only message file to send then change intent type:

```
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

try to look at this link:

[send message through whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)