# Cordova - Unable to trigger Android to let me choose an image to upload

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using Cordova to wrap a third party iframe. In the iframe there is an upload button. **It works on iOS**, I am able to select a photo to upload (see screenshot below).

[image]

**On Android** though nothing happens when I click the upload button that should prompt the user to open the gallery to select a file.

There are no errors in the console but I found this **error in LogCat**:
`No activity found to handle file chooser intent: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf }`

That error tells me that [the device has no applications installed that are able to handle that particular implicit intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40029732/activitynotfoundexception-when-attempting-to-launch-intent-in-cordova/40031280). But why can't it use the default Photos or Files App? When I try to upload an image using a mobile browser the Files App correctly shows up.

How can I solve?

- Do I need to grant additional permissions? I already added the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

- Am I missing a specific allow-intent in my config.xml?
  My current settings are these:

```
  <allow-intent href="https://*.mydomain.com.*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
```

- Do I need to install an additional Cordova plugin?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I realized that it's not a permissions issue.

It works when I manually change the third party upload button HTML to `<input type="file" />`.