# File upload not working for Android in Cordova project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ng-file-upload

In my Cordova project I rely on a third party dependency that uses [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/480) in order to upload files.

It works on iOS but not on Android as reported in this [issue on their Github](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/480).

The old issue had been closed because the following solutions were available:

- https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#deprecated => NOW DEPRECATED
- Crosswalk => NOW DEPRECATED

How can I solve this? The HTTP request is not sent at all.

**Additional info:**

1. [Logs found in LogCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857558/cordova-unable-to-trigger-android-to-let-me-choose-an-image-to-upload):

`No activity found to handle file chooser intent.:`
`android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle`
`Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=`
`[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf }`

Explanation of the log:
`The error is telling you that the device has no applications installed that are able to handle that particular implicit intent.` -> that is not the case though

2. It does not seem to be a permissions issue:
   The (Cordova) Android App works when for the upload button I use `<input type="file" />` in place of the ng-file-upload directive.

( we already provide all the required permissions: )

```
        <custom-config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        </custom-config-file>
```

3. I am whitelisting everything in my config.xml for cordova: access, allow-navigation, allow-intent, CSP. Still no luck.
4. We don't have control over the Android code (unless we write a custom plugin). Would this native code solve the issue?

```
MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
MyWebviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Comment: I will give a **50 rep bounty** to whoever helps us solve this. Thanks :)

Comment: Update: I have been told that someone managed to make ng-file-upload work using inappbrowser. Giving it a try..

Answer (score 1):

We solved this bug adding the 2 lines of code below that were missing in the Lollipop (and greater versions) handler.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
    // FIX HERE vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv @@
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); 
    intent.setType("*/*");
    // FIX HERE ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ @@
```

This handler in your cordova project is located under: `src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java`.

Hopefully the contributors of `cordova-android` will fix this [reported issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/695) themselves so that we can remove our patch.

Comment: Better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55447711/convert-mime-types-in-filechooserparams-to-the-right-format-for-intent-settype