# Convert mime types in fileChooserParams to the right format for Intent.setType

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, webview, filepicker

I am trying to upload a file using a WebView in Android.

This is [the code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/2163c8ae0536bfde9029cfc981b945f4af93e09f/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebChromeClient.java#L252) in use:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@Override
public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
    LOG.d(LOG_TAG, "mime types: " + Arrays.toString(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()));
    // PRINTS [.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf] !!        
    try {
        parentEngine.cordova.startActivityForResult(new CordovaPlugin() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
                // ...
            }
        }, intent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
      // ...
    }
    return true;
}
```

The **problem** is that when the external library that I **must** use (`ng-file-upload`) triggers the execution of this method, the mime types passed as argument in fileChooserParams are: `[.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf]`. I don't see most of these in the [list of allowed mime types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065838/what-are-the-possible-intent-types-for-intent-settypetype).

As a consequence I find this error in LogCat:
`No activity found to handle file chooser intent.: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf }`

If I simply add `intent.setType("image/* application/pdf");` everything works as expected!

Now the **question** is: in the [Merge Request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/695) that I want to submit to [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/695)'s contributors how do I safely transform the *fileChooserParams* to the correct format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I improved the solution using this code:

```
   // Validation utility for mime types
    private List<String> extractValidMimeTypes(String[] mimeTypes) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> mimes;
        if (mimeTypes.length() == 1 && mimeTypes[0].contains(",")) {
            mimes = Arrays.asList(mimeTypes[0].split(","));
        } else {
            mimes = Arrays.asList(mimeTypes);
        }
        MimeTypeMap mtm = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        for (String mime : mimes) {
            if (mime != null && mime.trim().startsWith(".")) {
                String extensionWithoutDot = mime.trim().substring(1, mime.trim().length());
                String derivedMime = mtm.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extensionWithoutDot);
                if (derivedMime != null && !results.contains(derivedMime)) {
                    // adds valid mime type derived from the file extension
                    results.add(derivedMime);
                }
            } else if (mtm.getExtensionFromMimeType(mime) != null && !results.contains(mime)) {
                // adds valid mime type checked agains file extensions mappings
                results.add(mime);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }


public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, final ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathsCallback, final WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
    Intent intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
    List<String> validMimeTypes = extractValidMimeTypes(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes());
    if (validMimeTypes.isEmpty()) {
        intent.setType(DEFAULT_MIME_TYPE);
    } else {
        intent.setType(String.join(" ", validMimeTypes));
    }
    ...
```

See my [Pull Request](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/707/files) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved simply adding the following 2 lines in [my PR](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/pull/705):

```
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes());
```

**Outcome:**

`2019-04-01 00:18:00.501 32500-32500/my.app.bundle.id D/SystemWebChromeClient: : fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes(): [.jpg,.png,.tiff,.jpeg,.tif,.pdf]`

`2019-04-01 00:18:00.503 2225-2921/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=image/* cmp=com.android.documentsui/.picker.PickActivity (has extras)} from uid 10105`

I hope it will get accepted.

Comment: I switched to the other solution since this enforces the picker to have images as first choice. It may have issues in other Cordova Apps (eg. music picker).