# send whatsapp messages to someone not on contact list from android app

Tags: android, message, whatsapp

I'm developing an application that can send message through whatsapp. I have implemented it by following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp) but it only works for contacts that on my contact list. It keeps error when i try to send message to contacts that are not in my contact list although the user already registered on whatsapp using that number (contact). Here is the message from whatsapp:

[image: message from whatsapp]

here is my code:

```
    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto: " + smsNumber);
        //Timber.e("smsNumber %s", uri.toString());
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, ""));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

is there any solutions ?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: We can send whatsapp message to people in our network graph(if they are indirectly linked to some whatsapp group). But sending message to a total stranger, is not possible directly. I think whatsapp did this to protect people from message bots.

Answer (score 0):

you can send via WhatsApp API even if he is not in your contact

```
String whatsappUrl = String.format("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%s&text%s",PhoneNumber,msg);
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(whatsappUrl));
            browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            p_context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```