# Intent to Whatsapp with a Phone Number and Message

Tags: android

I want to send an intent to whatsapp with a phone number and a predefined message from my Application. Does whatsapp provide such intent service or if not, Is there any workaround?

Comment: yes you can send text to whatsapp through sharing intents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending message through WhatsApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462874/sending-message-through-whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

You can find this on official [site](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012).

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```