# send whatsapp message to specific number programmatically

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I'm developing an app, and I want to send a WhatsApp message to a specific number

I used this code from [Satheesh's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26335015/208273) and make corrections.
but the users who installed both WhatsApp messenger and business WhatsApp, this code send a message into business WhatsApp directly, it didn't show options to allow the users to choose between two apps

in android 5 it shows options but android 7 and 8 it didn't show options. it sends to business WhatsApp only.

can you help me to allow to give options to choose between both apps in android 7 and 8?

```
private void openWhatsApp (String phoneNumber) {

    boolean isWhatsappInstalled = whatsappInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");

    if (isWhatsappInstalled) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+phoneNumber));

        startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "WhatsApp not Installed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(goToMarket);
    }
}

private boolean whatsappInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i am sending whatapp message from my app with the help of this code:-

```
private void sendMsgOnSavedWhatsappNumber(String mobile) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.whatsapp", "com.whatsapp.Conversation"));
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid",
                PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("91" + mobile) + "@s.whatsapp.net");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
    }
```

Comment: please provide prodper code. i is for intent. but which action need to set ther. what is provided to package manager etc. share your function full

Comment: if this code will help you then appriciate the answer

Comment: this will open your whatsapp message screen for that user whom you want to send the message and i think you can't send whatsapp message to user from any other app

Comment: what  is "jid"? here

Comment: this is oppening the whatsapp message screen of that person shom you want to chat

Comment: thank you for your replaying, but it didn't open whatsapp with me!

Comment: what is you country code for mobile number ? replace the 91 with your country code. then it should work

Comment: replace 91 to 970 then try

Comment: the code that I was used works correctly
But if the user is installed both whatsapp messenger and business whataspp, I want to give him options to choose which one wants to send the message

Comment: in android 5 works correctly and give the user options to choose between the both apps
but my problem in android 7 and 8. it sends the message to business whatsapp only. it didn't give options to choose and it didn't send it to whatsapp messanger, it opens business whatsapp directly!
can you help me?